# Disabling Caliburn.Micro View/ViewModel binding convention for a given V/VM pair

Tags: mvvm, datatemplate, caliburn.micro

I love Caliburn Micro, but I am having some difficulty here:

I would like to *manually* define a DataTemplate to a given ViewModel subtype, but I don't know how to disable the automatic name-based convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From ["All About Conventions(Caliburn.Micro")](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/conventions) documentation:

> Should you decide that you don’t like the behavior of the
>   ViewModelBinder (more details below), it follows the same patterns as
>   the above framework services. It has several Funcs you can replace
>   with your own implementations, such as Bind, BindActions and
>   BindProperties. Probably the most important aspect of customization
>   though, is the ability to turn off the binder’s convention features.
>   To do this, set `ViewModelBinder.ApplyConventionsByDefault` to false.
>   If you want to enable it on a view-by-view basis, you can set the
>   `View.ApplyConventions` attached property to true on your View. This
>   attached property works both ways. So, if you have conventions on by
>   default, but need to turn them off on a view-by-view basis, you just
>   set this property to false.